# SSH to Github not working

Tags: ssh

SSH has been working fine for the last few weeks since I got my new PC.  I've had no problems but today I started getting:

`ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: resource temporarily unavailable`

I did some googling and found that there is a common issue with WSL which sometimes causes this, but I'm unable to SSH from my bash shell, or from cmd/powershell.

This is the part that confuses me, if I do: `ssh -T git@192.30.253.113` I am prompted for the password to my key, it successfully authenticates and responds with "Hi alexmk92! You've successfully authenticated".

Great, that at least proves that my firewall isn't blocking SSH on port 22.  But why does `git@github.com` throw the resource failed error?  My initial thought is that this could be a DNS problem.

So I tried to configure my network adapter to use Google's DNS server (`8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`) I even configured the IPV6 DNS servers just in case.  Following this I did an `ipconfig /flushdns`, attempted to connect via `git@github.com` again and BAM the same result, however `git@192.30.253.113` still works.

I'm guessing another potential cause is that `github.com` is behind a load balancer and one of the IP's on the cluster could be black-listed somewhere on my machine?  I'm just pulling guesses out of thin air now, any help would be greatly appreciated, this is driving me insane.

Comment: If your theory is correct, then browser too shouldn't have access to `github.com`. Have you tried url in a web browser ?

Comment: Hmmm yeah you're right, I can consistently connect to github.com in my browser, so that rules that out...it's just really weird that sshing with the IP directly works but using the DNS name doesn't...I'm totally stumped on this one

Comment: Try to do ssh over https port. [Read this](https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-over-the-https-port/).

Comment: Yep that works, it even works if I use `ssh -T -p 22 git@ssh.github.com` or `ssh -T git@ssh.github.com`.  It seems that my machine is having a problem with resolving `github.com`...very weird

Comment: @Mahesh thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I managed to get it working after you linked that article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some further Googling it turned out that my machine did not have a hosts entry for github.com and it was unable to automatically resolve it.

In Windows Subsystem for Linux I created a ssh config file

```
touch ~/.ssh/config
```

(for some reason the base distro of Ubuntu 18.04 on the windows marketplace didn't have one) I then had to make sure the file permissions were correct:

```
chmod 755 ~/.ssh/config
```

Once the file was created, I edited it with

```
sudo nano ~/.ssh/config
```

and added `github.com` as a Host.

```
Host github.com
  Hostname ssh.github.com
  Port 22
```

Upon saving, I ran

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

and attempted

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Everything now seems to be working.

Comment: This fixed it for me!

Answer (score 1):

In my case my ISP did not allow ssh, so it was not working from cmd and wsl both. Got around it using vpn

Answer (score 0):

To have successful SSH connection to Github, SSH key has to be import into Github

- Open Git bash or Terminal
- Run the command `ssh-keygen`
- Choose all default option

A private and a public key gets generated in the folder *** < user_home>/.ssh/***

- Login to Github.com
- Navigate to account settings
- Choose item "SSH and GPG Keys" from the side navigation bar
- click added new SSh key
- Copy and save public key content from *** < user_home>/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ***